# How to compile a Flutter application on a docker container on Intellij Idea?

Tags: docker, flutter, intellij-idea, containers

I have a full Docker image that has Flutter SDK, Android SDK, Dart SDK, etc, all installed and in the $PATH.

I made it work on Intellij Idea, I can click "deploy" and it launches, but then I don't know what else to do.

I thought Intellij Idea would work inside this container, and so it would find Dart SDK, etc, and work.

How can I compile my flutter project using the SDK from the container on Intellij Idea? And also how to use intellisense, etc, all from things inside the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is not something that is currently supported in IntelliJ, according to a [forum-post answered by JetBrains staff](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010641860-Is-remote-development-with-containers-supported-).

How I see it, you have three options:

1. Switch to Visual Studio Code and follow [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)
2. Use the in the forum-post mentioned [Projector](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/03/11/projector-is-out/), which runs your IDE on a Server and you can connect to it using a web browser, or a Electron desktop client
3. Expose your SDKs from your Docker container and set the paths manually on your host system

With #3 I mean something like this, when running your container:

```
docker container run -itd \
   -v /local/path/to/sdk:/docker/path/to/sdk \
   devimage
```

and then in your IDE you can set the path to that, or you could even set some environment variables like e.g. `ANDROID_HOME` to point to the local bind location.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

1. Go to File -> Project Structure
2. Set the path for Module, Library, Project, and SDK

Sometimes IntelliJ requires the PATH setup here.

Comment: this will get the SDK and other things from the host, not from the container